# for loop breaks dplyr pipe

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr

I'm currently trying to use a for loop to mutate many new columns at once. the origin data frame (advisor_attribute_V1) contains a "key" for which I use the grepl function to find the particular entry I want and then mark if that entry is present or not in the column:

```
###

attribute_expander <- function(x){
  for (i in unique(merged_data$Attributes)){
    attribute <- i
    advisor_attributes_V2 <- advisor_attributes_V2 %>%
      mutate(!!(attribute) := ifelse(grepl(attribute,Attributes,fixed = TRUE),"Y","N"))
  }
}

###


advisor_attributes_V2 <- advisor_attributes_V1 %>%
  (attribute_expander()) %>%
  select(Name,Login_ID,claim_user_key,c(unique(merged_data$Attributes)))
```

The functions seems to register fine, however when I do the bottom few lines of code, I get the error message :

> ```
> Error in `mutate()`:
> ! Problem while computing `Auto PD Core 1 = ifelse(grepl(attribute, Attributes, fixed = TRUE), "Y", "N")`.
> Caused by error in `grepl()`:
> ! object 'Attributes' not found
> ```

Where the column "Attributes" comes from the original data frame (my key essentially). When I don't pipe this loop and just do the code all manually it runs fine but I'm not sure if the problem stems from piping the function or not initializing something for the function to run.

EDIT -------------------------------------------------------

Essentially this is how the data is layered initially (V1) and the output I need (V2)

Sample Data

attributes V1:

| Attributes |
| --- |
| A/B/C/D |
| B/C/D |
| A/B |

attributes_V2:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Y | Y | Y | Y |
| N | Y | Y | Y |
| Y | Y | N | N |

The unique(merged_data$attributes) is simply a list of all the known attributes the loop may come accross (for this sample it would be c(A,B,C,D). Hope this clarifies things

Comment: The error message is confusing, but according to your code you are accessing `advisor_attributes_V2` inside your function before it was defined. The error you should *actually* be getting is therefore “object 'advisor_attributes_V2' not found”.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I just assumed that because I already started with the initial advisor_attributes_V2 <- advisor_attributes_V1 %>% function, when the function ran it kept that I'm starting the "V2" from "V1". Do you have any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Some other problems are that the function has an argument x which is never used, it needs to explicitly return something and the inputs are missing from the question so others can't run it.

Comment: It's very difficult to provide recommendations on fixing things without a reproducible example. We don't know what the data you're running this on looks like, or what the desired output is, and we can't test potential fixes without sample data.

Comment: @GregorThomas Sorry for the confusion. I updated my post with a sample of what my data looks like. Like I wrote in the initial post this seems to run fine when I just run things manually but the goal was to have it run more seamlessly (hence the function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df |>
  mutate(id = row_number()) |>
  separate_longer_delim(Attributes, delim = "/") |>
  mutate(value = "Y") |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = Attributes, values_from = value, values_fill = "N")
# # A tibble: 3 × 5
#      id A     B     C     D    
#   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 Y     Y     Y     Y    
# 2     2 N     Y     Y     Y    
# 3     3 Y     Y     N     N
```

---

Using this sample data:

```
df = read.table(text = 'Attributes
A/B/C/D
B/C/D
A/B', header = T)
```

Comment: Could it be some of these packages don't work together? These are the ones I currently have active and it keeps telling me the function separate_longer_delim does not exist (library(DBI)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(dfcr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
library(timeDate)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(readxl)
library(tidyr))

Comment: `separate_longer_delim` is in the new version of `tidyr` released in January - it is replacing an older function `separate_rows`. You can either update `tidyr` to the current version or use the older function, replacing that line with `separate_rows(Attributes, sep = "/") |>`.

Comment: Yes just figured that out. This works perfectly, thank you very much!